# xpath query not giving current date result

Tags: java, xpath, jcr

I am doing this xPath query it is working fine but it is giving one date earlier result
there it is not giving current date document, `06-06-2014`, its giving result based on `05-06-2014`

```
/jcr:root/eds:home/anuj/eds:personal//*[@jcr:primaryType eq 'eds:void' or (@jcr:primaryType eq 'eds:document' and (@eds:content/jcr:lastModified >= xs:dateTime('2014-06-05T00:00:00.000+05:30') and @eds:content/jcr:lastModified <= xs:dateTime('2014-06-06T00:00:00.000+05:30'))) and (@eds:docType='cashdept')] order by @jcr:score descending
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the XML?

Comment: no i have no xml example . do you have any idea.. what it can be?

Comment: I would guess it's a timezone issue, but without seeing the XML I'm groping in the dark. How do you know it's wrong if you don't know what's in the XML?